# preventDefault doesn't work with external links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following code:

**JS**

```
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    return true;
}
$("#close-link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $("#confirm").attr("href");
});
$("#confirm").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#go").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="dialog">
        <h3 class="top-bar">Leaving so soon?</h3>
        <span class="close-button-container">[<a href="#" onclick="overlay();" title="Close" id="close-link">X</a>]</span><br /><br /><br />
        Example text
        <br />No, take me <a href="#" hreflang="en-US" onclick="window.location.href = targetUrl;" id="go">there</a> anyway...
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Example Link" onclick="overlay()" id="confirm">Example Link</a>
```

**The Problem**

I tried adding a link to another site. But I wanted to add a confirmation box once this link is clicked. The `#close-link` is used to close the dialog and the `#confirm` link as seen above should open it. The `#go` link is inside the dialog and if clicked brings the user to the location of the `#confirm` link. But something went wrong... Now when I click `#confirm` it opens the dialog for a second and directly sends me to its `href`. Shouldn't `event.preventDefault` fix this? If so, then why doesn't it?

Comment: Because you do not have a return statement in your overlay function! Also move out the event handler from inside the function.

Comment: @lshettyl like this? Now the dialog remains but for some reason the `#go` link doesn't have a value in its `href`...

Comment: You would need to post your HTML and tell us where would `#go` get the `href` from and how.

Comment: You are using two events for one element, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a few things;

1. Remove all inline event handlers
2. When using jQuery, make the most of it and avoid writing vanilla javascript unless there is a reason to do so.
3. Do not use `A` for any other purpose than an actual link (The close button in your case). Use a button/other tags.

Take a look the below code and see if that's what you wanted.

```js
$("#confirm, #close-link").click(overlay);

function overlay(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var el = $("#overlay");
    el.css({"visibility": el.css("visibility") === "visible" && "hidden" || "visible"});
    if ( this.tagName === 'A' ) {
        el.find("a").attr("href", this.href);
    }
}
```

```css
#overlay {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="dialog">
        <h3 class="top-bar">Leaving so soon?</h3>
        <span class="close-button-container" id="close-link">[X]</span><br /><br /><br />
        Example text
        <br />No, take me <a href="#" hreflang="en-US" id="go">there</a> anyway...
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Example Link" id="confirm">Example Link</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add an event to `overlay(event)`. This function needs to prevent the click so it should have the `e.preventDefault()`

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Example Link" onclick="overlay(event);" id="confirm">Example Link</a>

function overlay(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        el = document.getElementById("overlay");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
        var href = event.target.href
        //If click button close
            //Hidden div, no go
        //If click button go
            //window.location = href
    }
```

**Explanation**

Your `<a>` has two events binded to it. One with `#confirm` and one with the inline `onclick=`. You should choose only one :)

Comment: So how would I workaround this use of 2 events for 1 element?

Comment: Suppress the `#confirm` chunk. There is no need for a `onclick` event on `#confirm`, just do the confirmation stuff inside the overlay. `#go` button will do the link job has the pop-up becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

If your code was called as part of an event listener callback, `event.preventDefault()` would work. But your code is running due to `onclick` which simply runs the function `overlay()` - attaching listeners to various elements (`#close-link`, `#go`, `#confirm`) using jQuery. After the listeners are attached, they start listening for events, which never come since the `<a href="...">` changes the page.

**Solution**:

It is best to stop using `on*` attributes for all your codes. Take it out. Then use only event listeners for all your needs.

```
$('#confirm').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this will work

    // Do your toggle visibility and whatever else you need here.
});
```

There are other possible solutions that continue to use `onclick` calling a function, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the click event to the `#confirm` element inside `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#confirm").on("click", function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
              });
         });
```